# Azure.CloudService 2.7 incompatible with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: azure, cloud, visual-studio-2005

For some reason after I installed VS 2015 the project CloudService of azure SDK incompatible and can't be opened.

I tried to setup new project but then it throws this error:
[image]

Should I install something specific for Azure SDK 2.7? Why we have this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out! Eventually! If Azure SDK 2.7 (in my case) was installed before VS2015 (in my case), then you need to run the SDK installer again after you install VS and then select "Repair" option. Then it will install proper links to the project templates to new VS

Comment: Thank you for the information, there's Azure SDK update to be done and I'm trying..